# Failed to read HTTP message error due to null value passing to id :spring-boot,kotlin,mongodb

Tags: mongodb, kotlin

I'm completely new to kotlin programming and the mongo db.I'm defining a data class, which all the data fields are not **nullable** and all the fileds are **val**

```
data class Order( @Id
                  val id: String,
                  val customerId: String,
                  val externalTransactionId : String,
                  val quoteId :String,
                  val manifestItems : List<ManifestItem>,
                  val externalTokenNumber : String,
                  val deliveryId : String,
                  val quoteCreatedTime: String,
                  val deliveryCreatedTime: String,
                  val status : String,
                  val deliveryInfo: DeliveryInfo,
                  val pickupInfo: PickupInfo,
                  val riderId : String,
                  val currency : String,
                  val expiryTime : String,
                  val trackingUrl : String,
                  val complete:Boolean,
                  val updated:String
)
```

and I'm sending a http request with following body

```
{

    "pickupAddress":"101 Market St, San Francisco, CA 94105",
    "deliveryAddress":"101 Market St, San Francisco, CA 94105",
    "deliveryExpectedTime":"2018-07-25T23:31:38Z",
    "deliveryAddressLatitude":7.234,
    "deliveryAddressLongitude":80.000,
    "pickupLatitude":7.344,
    "pickupLongitude":8.00,
    "pickupReadyTime":""

}
```

in my router class I'm get the request body to order object and send to the service class

```
  val request = serverRequest.awaitBody<Order>()
  val quoteResponse =  quoteService.createQuote(request,customerId)
```

in my service class I'm saving the order to database

```
 suspend fun createQuote(order: Order,customerId:String):QuoteResponse {
        ordersRepo.save(order).awaitFirst()
           //generating quote response here
        return quoteResponse
}
```

the **id** is generating at the database.and I'm having this kind of error when sending the request

```
org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebInputException: 400 BAD_REQUEST "Failed to read HTTP message"; nested exception is org.springframework.core.codec.DecodingException: JSON decoding error: Instantiation of [simple type, class basepackage.repo.Order] value failed for JSON property id due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter id which is a non-nullable type; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.MissingKotlinParameterException: Instantiation of [simple type, class basepackage.repo.Order] value failed for JSON property id due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter id which is a non-nullable type
 at [Source: (org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DefaultDataBuffer$DefaultDataBufferInputStream); line: 12, column: 1] (through reference chain: basepackage.repo.Order["id"])
```

How do I overcome that problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mongoDB, you need to use ObjectID instead of String and it could not generate by itself and you need to create it every time!

Following code probably is a solution :

```
data class Order constructor(
        @Id
        @field:JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer::class)
        @field:JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
        var id: ObjectId?,
        val customerId: String,
        val externalTransactionId: String,
        val quoteId: String,
        val manifestItems: List<ManifestItem>,
        val externalTokenNumber: String,
        val deliveryId: String,
        val quoteCreatedTime: String,
        val deliveryCreatedTime: String,
        val status: String,
        val deliveryInfo: DeliveryInfo,
        val pickupInfo: PickupInfo,
        val riderId: String,
        val currency: String,
        val expiryTime: String,
        val trackingUrl: String,
        val complete: Boolean,
        val updated: String
)
```

- I converted `val` to `var` that it lets you set value to it after serialize, set access as `READ_ONLY` that Jackson doesn't expects id as input anymore.
- `ToStringSerializer` is optional, if you like id as String